# AWS deployment "Unable to remove top level folder"

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

I have installed the Bitbucket addon to deploy with AWS CodeDeploy but for an unknown reason, I get this error **"Unable to remove top level folder"** when I try to deploy from the bitbucket view.

[image]

This is my appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
   - source: /
   destination: /var/www/citytwig
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/configure.sh
    timeout: 300
    runas: root
```

I have already deployed other bitbucket repositories successfully, I'm wondering why this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long searching, I realized that a file had Russian characters on his filename.
It seems that the Bitbucket CodeDeploy Addon have issues with this kind of characters.

Comment: jlorie - We are facing the same issue but in our case, the characters are present in the node_modules folder which are package names for node dependencies.
Eg: @agm,@angular 
We are using node with angular and hence these dependencies need to be checked in. If we remove these folders the deployment works successfully.

Answer (score 4):

Aws codedeploy tries to rollback previous deployment before it applies a new one. It can happen that you have deleted some files manually on the instance and now rollback script is failing.

**Solution**

Delete rollback scripts of `codedeploy-agent` on the instance.

if you are using ubuntu, ssh into instance and go to the directory

```
cd /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-instructions/
```

and look for a file that ends with `-cleanup`

delete this file.

Now try you deployment again.

Check out [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-rollback-and-redeploy.html), or read it in `Rollback and Redeployment Workflow` section of [pdf](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-user.pdf)

Depending on the rollback script the Deployment may fail with different messages, for me it was `Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir`

But it always fails on `Install` Event.

Comment: this is the same error I get were u able to fix it?

Comment: yes, I fixed it and I wrote a whole answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the exact error, but in my case, it was a typo in the file name *appspec.yml*